I need help sending a put event on AWS Eventbridge
I’m fighting with this code
defmodule MyApp.Eventbridge do
  @moduledoc false
  require Logger

  def send_event_to_eventbridge() do
    event = %{
      Source: "car-event",
      DetailType: "car-created",
      Detail: %{
        brand: "Renault",
        name: "A4",
        country: "US"
      },
      EventBusName: "my-event-bus"
    }


    event_json = Poison.encode(event)

    Logger.info("Send: #{inspect(event_json)}")
    case ExAws.EventBridge.put_events(event_json) |> ExAws.request() do
      {:ok, response} ->
        Logger.info("Successfully: #{inspect(response)}")
      {:error, error} ->
        Logger.error("Error: #{inspect(error)}")
    end
  end
end


and I don’t know how to fix this error
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:ok, "{\"EventBusName\":\"my-event-bus\",\"Detail\":{\"country\":\"US\",\"brand\":\"Renault\",\"name\":\"A4\"},\"DetailType\":\"car-created\",\"Source\":\"car-event\"}"} of type Tuple. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): DBConnection.PrepareStream, DBConnection.Stream, Date.Range, Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, Jason.OrderedObject, List, Map, MapSet, Phoenix.LiveView.LiveStream, Postgrex.Stream, Range, Stream
    (elixir 1.14.0) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir 1.14.0) lib/enum.ex:166: Enumerable.reduce/3
    (elixir 1.14.0) lib/enum.ex:4307: Enum.map/2
    (ex_aws_eventbridge 0.1.1) lib/ex_aws/event_bridge.ex:88: ExAws.EventBridge.put_events/2
    (my_app 0.1.0) lib/my_app/eventbridge.ex:22: MyApp.Eventbridge.send_event_to_eventbridge/0

I did the test with the Java language and I did see it in the logs but in Elixir I couldn't set the event to display it in the logs.

This error had to do with what I mentioned in my answer. Would you mind updating your question to include the other error you're now getting from EventBridge?

You're using Poison.encode/1, which returns a tuple in the form {:ok, encoded_data}. You can either extract it from the tuple, doing something like:
{:ok, event_json} = Poison.encode(event)

Which will raise an error if the encoding isn't successful.
Or, you can use Poison.encode!/1 instead, which directly returns a value instead of a tuple, or raises an error if the encoding is not successful.

I was able to get it now, I’ll leave it here for other users.
defmodule MyApp.EventBridge do
  @moduledoc false
  require Logger
  alias ExAws.EventBridge

  def send_event_to_eventbridge(source, detail_type, detail, event_bus_name) do
    event = %{
      "Source": source,
      "DetailType": detail_type,
      "Detail":  Poison.encode!(detail),
      "EventBusName": event_bus_name
    }

    Logger.info("Sending: #{inspect(event)}" )

    case EventBridge.put_events([event]) |> ExAws.request() do
      {:ok, response} ->
        Logger.info("Event ID: #{inspect(response)}")

      {:error, error} ->
        Logger.error("Error #{inspect(error)}")
    end
  end
end

I insert the data through the console
MyApp.EventBridge.send_event_to_eventbridge(
   "car-event",
   "car-created",
   %{brand: "Renault", name: "A4", country: "US"},
   "my-event-bus"
  )

Result:
[info] Sending: %{Source: "car-event", DetailType: "car-created", Detail: "{\"country\":\"US\",\"brand\":\"Renault\",\"name\":\"A4\"}", EventBusName: "my-event-bus"}

[info] Event ID: %{"Entries" => [%{"EventId" => "e4accabf-b89d-0dd2-0fff-92e6de215a95"}], "FailedEntryCount" => 0}

